# echo data before finishing run function in PHP

Tags: php

I have vary long process that gets data from different API's and then writes a lot of data to a database.

I want to display all the data that gets returned from the API's immediately and then add the data to the database. (I do not want to the user to have to wait till the database has finished with its process).

I tried to implement the `ob_flush()` function, this is my code :

```
$content = array_merge($this->api1Result, $this->api2Result);

//return to the client the result
ob_start();
$this->taskFinished($result);
ob_flush();
//After all content return to client add all content to Database
//$this->addContentToDatabase();
```

For the first request that I made, it looks like its working great (it takes 2-3 seconds for the result to be displayed to the client). In the next requests, however, it becomes too slow (it takes 20-30 seconds).

Am I using the `ob_flush` function correctly?

Comment: You need to use `flush()` too after `ob_flush()`  in-order to completely flush

Comment: You *use* the function, not implement it...